# trying to get jquery to load html

Tags: jquery

I can load up html like this

```
 $('#grid').empty();
  for (i in main_images) {
 $('#grid').append($('<li gallery="'+i+'"><div class="title">'+(titles[i] )+'</div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src= '+main_images[i]+'/><span></span></a></li>'));
}
```

but I can't seem to do it for this.

```
 <div id="container" boarder ="0">
<ul><li><img src="'+img+'"/></li></ul>
  <span class="button prevButton "></span>
  <span class="button nextButton"></span>
  <span> <a href="#" class="zoom_back"></a></span>
  <span> <a href="#" class="zoom_big"></a></span>
  <span> <a href="#" class="info"></a></span>
  <span> <a href="#" class="info_on"></a></span>
  <span> <a href="#" class="info_box"></a></span>
  <span> <a class="info_box_title">title</a></span>
  <span> <a class="info_box_status">status</a></span>
  <span> <a class="info_box_about"> about about </a></span>
  <span> <a href="#" class="box_counter" ></a></span>
     </div>
```

I tried this but it throws an error

```
$('#container').empty();
$('#container').append($('<ul><li><img src="'+img+'"/></li></ul>
<span class="button prevButton "></span>
<span class="button nextButton"></span>
<span> <a href="#" class="zoom_back"></a></span>
<span> <a href="#" class="zoom_big"></a></span>
<span> <a href="#" class="info"></a></span>
<span> <a href="#" class="info_on"></a></span>
<span> <a class="info_box"></a></span>
<span> <a class="info_box_title">title</a></span>
<span> <a class="info_box_status">status</a></span>
<span> <a class="info_box_about"> about</a></span>
<span> <a href="#" class="box_counter" ></a></span>
 '));
```

Comment: Could you shorten the example to include only the important parts? Also, could you provide the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have newline characters in a JS string. Unless you escape them with `\` (in which case they are ignored and it is as though there is no newline in your string. If you actually had a need for a newline in your string you would use `\n` instead of a literal newline):

```
$('#container').append('<ul><li><img src="'+img+'"/></li></ul>\
<span class="button prevButton "></span>\
<span class="button nextButton"></span>\
<span> <a href="#" class="zoom_back"></a></span>\
<span> <a href="#" class="zoom_big"></a></span>\
<span> <a href="#" class="info"></a></span>\
<span> <a href="#" class="info_on"></a></span>\
<span> <a class="info_box"></a></span>\
<span> <a class="info_box_title">title</a></span>\
<span> <a class="info_box_status">status</a></span>\
<span> <a class="info_box_about"> about</a></span>\
<span> <a href="#" class="box_counter" ></a></span>\
');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code instead of yours.

```
 $('#grid').append('<li gallery="'+i+'"><div class="title">'+(titles[i] )+'</div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src= '+main_images[i]+'/><span></span></a></li>');
```

You'r tring to append jQuery selected object to grid.

Comment: That's from the code example that the OP says already works. Please see the rest of the question. Incidentally, appending a jQuery object also works. http://jsfiddle.net/3WbRp/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the HTML in $() since that is used for selecting an element. You have already selected the container ID to append  HTML to.

Also, to add a new line to organize code better but not necessarily add a new line to your html, use "\".

```
$('#container').empty();
$('#container').append('<ul><li><img src="'+img+'"/></li></ul> \
<span class="button prevButton "></span> \
<span class="button nextButton"></span><span> \
<a href="#" class="zoom_back"></a></span> \
<span> <a href="#" class="zoom_big"></a></span> \
<span> <a href="#" class="info"></a></span> \
<span><a href="#" class="info_on"></a></span> \
<span> <a class="info_box"></a></span> \
<span> <a class="info_box_title">title</a></span> \
<span> <a class="info_box_status">status</a></span> \
<span> <a class="info_box_about"> about</a></span> \
<span> <a href="#" class="box_counter" ></a></span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dF7Wf/1/